# How to fetch data from json object and show in table

Tags: ajax, json

I have json object with data in following format.

```
{'data': {'series': ['2010-05-29',
                     '2010-05-30',
                     '2010-05-31',
                    ],
          'values': {'account-page'   : {'2010-05-30': 1,},
                     'splash features': {'2010-05-29': 6,
                                         '2010-05-30': 4,
                                         '2010-05-31': 5,
                                        }
                    }
          },
  'legend_size': 2}
```

Please help me to get data from  'Values' to create table like

```
column1            column2              column3
"Acount-page"      2010-05-30            1
"splash features"  2010-05-29            6
                   2010-05-30            4
                   2010-05-31            5
```

or any other way to create table

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of using single quotes you need to use double quotes. As it stands your JSON is not valid; you can validate your JSON at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Get a json parser here https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js
Then use:

```
var jsonstr = '{"data": {"series": ["2010-05-29", "2010-05-30", "2010-05-31" ], "values": {"account-page": {"2010-05-30": 1}, "splash features": {"2010-05-29": 6, "2010-05-30": 4, "2010-05-31": 5 } } }, "legend_size": 2}';
var json = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
console.log(json); // Note: Only supported in Safari and FF
```

With that you can do json.data.values, json.data.series, etc.

Comment: thanks for reply.Actualy after that i am not able to get all values from Values

Comment: You had some compatibility problems with quotes and commas in your json string, I updated the code in my answer.